# Problem loading tif into raster dataset in ArcSDE 10.2

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, raster-dataset

I have over 1000 raster datasets I need to mosaic into ArcSDE 10.2.  I can't use a mosaic dataset because the county I am working for wants to keep the files on an external HD, so the pointers won't work.  Unfortunately, I ran into this 10.2 bug when defining a spatial reference for the parent raster dataset:

http://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2014/1/28/updating-raster-datasets-in-geodatabases-at-102.html

The problem is that when I try the suggested workaround and create a raster dataset without a defined spatial reference, loading data is MUCH slower, meaning it will take weeks or possibly months to load everything.  I am building pyramids with Bilinear sampling, and LZ77 compression.  Any suggestions as to how I can speed up this process?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using pre-determined projection, The loading will be a bit slower. However, You may like to build statistics before loading TIFF's into raster dataset, Also, Please don't build pyramids or use different compression since this would increase the timing. You can do that after everything is loaded.

Additionally, Have you tried using command prompt for loading data? (for ex. sderaster command) I have always found that command prompt reduces almost 50% time then using ArcCatalog.
You can get more information here:
http://links.esri.com/gsb-sde-admin-cmds-ref

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will look into using command prompt. You were right about the pyramids and compression.  The Mosaicing process took significantly less time without building pyramids.